# How do I return the latest int a and not the first one that was entered?

Tags: java

I want this method to return an odd integer that is bigger/equal to 1.

The problem is that it always returns the first integer that was entered and not the latest.
Is there any way to fix that? thanks

```
public class muster
{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int a = alpha();
        System.out.println(a);
        
    }

    public static int alpha() {
        
        int a = Db.readInt("odd integer >= 1");
        
        
        if (a % 2 == 0 || a < 1) {
            alpha();
            
        }
        
        else {
            
        }
        return a;
        
    }
}
```

I want this method to return a odd integer that is bigger/equal to 1.

The problem is that it always returns the first integer that was entered and not the latest.
Is there any way to fix that? thanks

Comment: I would guess you probably just forgot to use the return value of your recursive method call. Meaning: Change `alpha();` to `return alpha();` inside your alpha method.

Comment: Honest recommendation: Change the recursion to a do while loop. Even if it is an unlikely case, if you keep entering wrong numbers, `alpha()` keeps being called and will enter stackoverflow state at some point.

Comment: As the two comments above, it's because you are always returning the object created the first time `alpha()` gets called.